# TextBlock.GetBindingExpression returning NULL

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The following is returning NULL for me, any idea why?

```
MultiBinding collectionRange = new MultiBinding();
collectionRange.Bindings.Add(new Binding("CurrentPosition") { Source = View });
collectionRange.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Count") { Source = View });
collectionRange.StringFormat = "{0} of {1}";
tbFooter.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, collectionRange);
var x = tbFooter.GetBindingExpression(TextBlock.TextProperty);
```

The MultiBinding is fine - the properties are valid and it renders on the UI ..I just can't seem to grab the binding expression (x is always NULL)

Am I using this method wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> This method is really just a convenience wrapper around the
>   BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression method. GetBindingExpression
>   passes the current instance and the dp parameter to
>   BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression.
>
> If your binding is a MultiBinding, use
>   BindingOperations.GetMultiBinding.

See "Remarks" section and notes in "Examples" section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.getbindingexpression.aspx).