# BindingExpression always returns null on Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, behavior

I created a behavior so I can change the UpdateSourceTrigger on a textbox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace xxxxxx.xxx.Behaviors
{
public static class InputBindingValidation
{
    public static DependencyProperty ValidateDataErrorsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                   "ValidateDataErrors",
                   typeof(bool),
                   typeof(InputBindingValidation),
                   new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnValidateDataErrors));

    private static void OnValidateDataErrors(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = target as TextBox;
        if (element == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This behavior can be attached to a TextBox item only.");
        }

        // TEST 1
        BindingExpression be = element.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (be != null)
        {
            be.ParentBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            be.ParentBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
            element.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, be.ParentBinding);
            be.UpdateSource();
        }
    }

    public static void SetValidateDataErrors(DependencyObject d, bool value)
    {
        d.SetValue(ValidateDataErrorsProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetValidateDataErrors(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return (bool)d.GetValue(ValidateDataErrorsProperty);
    }
}
```

}

I use it in my xaml :

```
<efw:EditViewBase x:Class="DocumentManager.View.DocumentEditView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:efw="clr-namespace:FPLQ.EFW.Base;assembly=FPLQ.EFW"
         xmlns:efwcontrol="clr-namespace:FPLQ.EFW.Controls;assembly=FPLQ.EFW.Controls"
         xmlns:b="clr-namespace:xxxx.xxx.Behaviors;assembly=FPLQ.EFW"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="518" d:DesignWidth="979"
         d:DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource VMLocator}, Path=DocumentEDVM}">
<GroupBox Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=MainGrid}" >
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                             Style="{StaticResource TextBoxNotes}" 
                             Text="{Binding Path=EntityViewModel.Title, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                             IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=EntityViewModel.IsReadOnlyNever}"
                             b:InputBindingValidation.ValidateDataErrors="True"/>
```

The "element.GetBindingExpression" line always returns null, how can I pull it off?

Tried this too, with no good result :

```
         Binding newBinding = new Binding();
         newBinding.ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
         newBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
         element.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, newBinding);
```

Anybody can help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: firstly, why haven't you create a proper WPF Behavior to do this? An example can be found here - http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html

Comment: Because I don't use Expression Blend.

Comment: so, behaviors aren't just about expression blend, they are the correct way to do what you want

Comment: [TextBlock.GetBindingExpression returning NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033021/textblock-getbindingexpression-returning-null)

Comment: what are you trying to do, it is not clear from the question?

Comment: Salvaged comment from @Rachel (from a deleted answer):  "The item is null because it is evaluated before the binding occurs. As a workaround, try using the Dispatcher to execute your code at a lower DispatcherPriority than DataBind to ensure it runs after your binding has been set and evaluated."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the OnValidateDataErrors was called before the binding being applied so the GetBindingExpression always returned null. Here's my final solution, it works fine.

using

```
            if (GetValidateDataErrors(target))
                element.Initialized += InitializeDataError;
            else
                element.Initialized -= InitializeDataError;
```

did the trick.

Full code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using System.Windows.Data;
using xxxx.EFW.Helper;

namespace xxxx.EFW.Behaviors
{
    public sealed class InputBindingValidation
    {
        public static DependencyProperty ValidateDataErrorsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                   "ValidateDataErrors",
                   typeof(bool),
                   typeof(InputBindingValidation),
                   new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnValidateDataErrors));

        private static void OnValidateDataErrors(DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var element = target as TextBox;

            if (GetValidateDataErrors(target))
                element.Initialized += InitializeDataError;
            else
                element.Initialized -= InitializeDataError;
        }

        private static void InitializeDataError(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var element = sender as TextBox;
            if (element == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("This behavior can be attached to a TextBox item only.");

            BindingExpression be = element.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
            if (be != null)
            {
                Binding bind = new Binding()
                                {
                                    Path = be.ParentBinding.Path,
                                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                                    Mode = be.ParentBinding.Mode,
                                    Converter = be.ParentBinding.Converter,
                                    ValidatesOnDataErrors = true
                                };
                if (be.ParentBinding.Source != null)
                    bind.Source = be.ParentBinding.Source;

                element.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bind);
            }
        }

        public static void SetValidateDataErrors(DependencyObject d, bool value)
        {
            d.SetValue(ValidateDataErrorsProperty, value);
        }

        public static bool GetValidateDataErrors(DependencyObject d)
        {
            return (bool)d.GetValue(ValidateDataErrorsProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I believe this does what you want, when the ValidateDataErrors property on the ChangeBindingBehavior is True it modifies the Text binding to have the value of UpdateSourceTrigger to be UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged.

Note: to use this you will need to reference System.Windows.Interactivity, this can be got from nuGet via the any of the packages offer this assembly (dll), there is an offical MS one but I can't seem to find the name.

XAML:

```
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeTextValue}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <app:ChangeBindingBehavior ValidateDataErrors="True" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </TextBox>
```

The code behind in the behavior:

```
public sealed class ChangeBindingBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidateDataErrorsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ValidateDataErrors",
        typeof (bool),
        typeof (ChangeBindingBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnValidateDataErrorsChanged));

    public bool ValidateDataErrors
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ValidateDataErrorsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValidateDataErrorsProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private static void OnValidateDataErrorsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.OldValue == args.NewValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        ((ChangeBindingBehavior)d).OnValidateDataErrorsChanged((bool)args.NewValue);
    }

    private void OnValidateDataErrorsChanged(bool newValue)
    {
        if (AssociatedObject == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var expression = AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (expression != null)
        {
            if (newValue)
            {
                var newBinding = new Binding("Text")
                {
                    Path = expression.ParentBinding.Path,
                    Source = AssociatedObject.DataContext,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                    Mode = expression.ParentBinding.Mode,
                    Converter = expression.ParentBinding.Converter
                };

                AssociatedObject.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, newBinding);
                AssociatedObject.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        OnValidateDataErrorsChanged(ValidateDataErrors);
    }
}
```